# Use PyWin32 to execute VBA Macro from Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, api, pywin32

I have two Excel Files and I can execute Macro **ReadBM_AP_Data**, but not **PythonScript**. For this function I used PyWin32 with the Function **RunApplication**

Here is the Python Code:

```
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application", pythoncom.CoInitialize())
    #C:\Users\dx5entir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject
    xl.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/dx5entir/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/FapsXML.xlsm")
    xl.RunApplication("FapsXML.xlsm!Modul1.PythonScript()")
    #xl.Application.Run('ReadEC_DC_Data.xlsm!Modul2.ReadBM_AP_Data()')
    xl.Application.Quit()
```

If I open the Excel File and start **PythonScript** it works.

This is the Error Messages:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\dx5entir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "C:\Users\dx5entir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 205, in run
> self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue)
> File "C:\Users\dx5entir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 381, in dispatch_events
> handler.dispatch(event)
> File "C:\Users\dx5entir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py", line 271, in dispatch
> self.on_any_event(event)
> File "C:\Users\dx5entir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 54, in on_any_event
> start_xl()
> File "C:\Users\dx5entir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 68, in start_xl
> xl.Application.Run("FapsXML.xlsm!Modul1.PythonScript()")
> File "<COMObject >", line 8, in Run
> File "C:\Users\dx5entir\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 368, in *ApplyTypes*
> result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> pywintypes.com_Serror: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Das Makro 'FapsXML.xlsm!Modul1.PythonScript()' kann nicht ausgeführt werden. Das Makro ist möglicherweise in dieser Arbeitsmappe nicht verfügbar, oder alle Makros wurden deaktiviert.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

I implement a watchdog to trigger this Event, but it still works with the other macro, so I see no problem with that.

Name Excel Sheets:

[image]

Name of Module and Sub:

[image]

- At the beginning my Excel Sheets had spaces. So I fixed that.
- I tried other macros and they worked. This macro **PythonScript** is working when I start it manually in the Excel file.
- I called the function per Button and not trigger it with a watchdog event. Same error.
- I updated my PythonInterpreter to Python 3.11.1 and updated every Python Packages in my Enviroment

Im confused why this function doesn't work with this macro, when this macro works when i start it manually and other macros works when I use PyWin32. I have no clue to fix that problem. Any advices? :)

Comment: There is no RunApplication method for the Application object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)  Just use `xl.Run()` as `xl` is an Application object already. But I suspect your problem is the `()` on the macro name: leave that off, so just `xl.Run("FapsXML.xlsm!Modul1.PythonScript")`

Comment: Hey yeah I removed the () and it works. Thank you really much!